# Command-line equivalent of CSS filter

Tags: css, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm currently working with pictures and I try to do the same thing as the CSS filter below but **in command line**:

```
filter: invert(0.86) hue-rotate(180deg);
```

To do the trick I used `imagemagick`'s `convert` tool.

```
convert $in -evaluate add -26% -negate -modulate 100,100,0 $out
```

I get close to the result I expect, but I have a huge quality drop. Let's show this in an example

Original version (a random jpg image)
[image: Original]
Clean version (made with CSS, expected result)
[image: Clean version]
Dirty one, made with convert
[image]

Is there any way (with this tool or another) to convert my image smoothly? The best would be to directly apply css to this image but I don't know whether it's possible in commandline...

Comment: Are you sure you are providing a JPG image to CSS? The artifacts you are seeing are due to JPG compression. Might you actually be providing a PNG or TIFF input to CSS. If not, then CSS is doing something else to smooth the colors. Or perhaps doing more processing that indicated by the simple commands you provide. Note that the inverse of 86% would be 14%. Though that does not help the artifacts.

Comment: I'm providing the same exact jpg image for both. I tried with a PNG and I still have the same quality loss. I choose 26% because at this value white get the exact same tone as `invert(0.86)` I expected 28% `2*(1-0.86)` but 26% actually fits better.

Do you know how to change convert's behavior to do what I want or do it with any other tool callable from my commandline?

Comment: Sorry, no. I do not know how CSS is removing the JPG artifacts.

Comment: Add the code plis

Comment: @Nicolás Alarcón Rapela The code used is shown in the original post (e.g. for css : `filter: invert(0.86) hue-rotate(180deg);`)

Comment: Perfect @MaximeB. I review

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela Do you have any news?

Comment: The busy state in the afternoon reviewed it. @MaximeB.